# Hangfire using multiple connection string and DbContext

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, hangfire

I'm having trouble using Hangfire with multiple connections on the Entity Framework. I have only one server that stores Hangfire jobs and each Job must be run with a different connection string. Example: I have 5 jobs stored and each job that launches must use a specific connection in its DbContext. In the requests of my API application I use HttpContext where I already inform through it which database should I use in the connection string. I am unable to inform an HttpContext to the hangfire and thus take advantage of the logic that already works. I am using dependency injection so the instances are created as soon as the job triggers the method. I could pass the name of the database as a parameter of the method that Hangfire should trigger, however I can't do anything with this information since I'm using Dependency Injection and at that moment the DbContext instances have already been created and without the connection string. Has anyone ever needed something like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the hangfire documents you'll get your answer.

[Hangfire document](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/running-multiple-server-instances.html)

```
It is possible to run multiple server instances inside a process, machine, or on several machines at the same time. Each server use distributed locks to perform the coordination logic.
```

Each Hangfire Server has a unique identifier that consist of two parts to provide default values for the cases written above. The last part is a process id to handle multiple servers on the same machine. The former part is the server name, that defaults to a machine name, to handle uniqueness for different machines. Examples: **server1:9853**, **server1:4531**, **server2:6742**.

Since the defaults values provide uniqueness only on a process level, you should handle it manually if you want to run different server instances inside the same process:

```
   r options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
{
    ServerName = String.Format(
        "{0}.{1}",
        Environment.MachineName,
        Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
};

var server = new BackgroundJobServer(options);

// or

app.UseHangfireServer(options);
```

Comment: I just want to have one server. All of my Jobs are stored in a database. My application is Multitenancy where I have an application with several databases (one per customer). I need each Job to execute with the specific connection string, for example, I have 10 databases where each one has a table of Clients and I need to update the Status of each one, so in this case I should have 10 Jobs and in each one of them I can identify the connection that must be used in DbContext so that the DI creates its instance with the proper connection and manipulates the data from that database only.

Comment: My problem is exactly at this point, I can even pass the name of my database to the method, however when the call arrives at the method all my DbContext are already injected into my Repositories and without the correct connection string.

Comment: I couldn't understand how multiple servers would help with my problem. Whenever the method is called it would have the same problem of not having to configure the connection string in the Startup for example.

Comment: As per my understanding of above comment you have to make one "Master" database that have database name and then you have to use these we are using same way to in old monolithic application. Now for hangfire you have to create one another application if in case web then use as api with parameters call in main application and in hangfire application run your all  job based on your parameters and all stored database name in Master database.